# top panel black again after I set the transparency

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

In unity I set panel opacity to transparent, then I do the following:

- Open Workspace Switcher
- Drag a full screen window to another workspace twice

And the top panel change black.

Comment: unity 2d or unity 3d?

Comment: How did you set the panel opacity? I was able to reproduce what you describe. I moved a window to worksapce 2, then 3, then and back, selecting full screen after each move. problem only occurred when returning to workspace 1. I've also seen this across reboots although that manifestation has for the most part stopped happening.

Comment: When the problem occurs, Tweak still thinks the opacity hasn't been changed. If I move the slider to 1 than back to .3 where I had it all is back to normal. It's as if there are times when the panel is regenerated but the opacity value isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Was the 'launcher capture mouse' option in the Unity Compiz plugin disabled? I flicked mine back on and the top panel opacity started working again just fine.